# cannot open apps on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, gui

I cannot open apps like `qbittorrennt`, `teamviewer` any more I tried adding permision

```
xhost +si:localuser:root
```

but no luck. Opening `teamviewer` gives this output

```
Init...
CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer ...
Launching TeamViewer GUI ...
Aborted (core dumped)
```